# How to hide a parent div and replace it with another div when user clicks on a button that is a children of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component that has to buttons, when the user clicks on one of the buttons I would like to hide the whole component and replace it with another component.

I was able to hide the clicked button, but couldn't hide the whole parent component when the child (button) is clicked.

What would be the best approach to do what I want to do ?

Here is my current code :(It's just hidding the pressed button)

```
    const ParentComponentStyle = {
      width:300,
      height:60,
      backgroundColor:"#343458"
    };

    class ParentCompnent extends React.Component {

     constructor(props){
         super(props) 
            this.state = {
               buttonPressed:false,
               opacity:1
         }
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }


      handleClick(evt) {
        this.setState({
          buttonPressed: !this.state.buttonPressed,
          opacity: 0,
       })
     }

    render(){
      return(
        <div className="DivToHide" style={ParentComponentStyle}>
            <div onClick={this.handleClick} style={{float:'left'}}>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
            <div onClick={this.handleClick} style={{float:"right", opacity: this.state.opacity}}>{this.props.children[1]}</div>
        </div>


       );
    }
}



export default ParentComponent;
```

And here is the component that I want to show once the other one has been hidden:

```
  const ShowThisDivStyle = {
      width:300,
      height:200,
      backgroundColor:"#343458"
  };

  var ShowThisDiv = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
      return(
      <div style={ShowThisDivStyle}>
            <div style={{float:'left'}}>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
            <p style={{float:"left", color:"white",marginTop: "7px"}}>{this.props.children[1]}</p>
            <div style={{float:"right"}}>{this.props.children[2]}</div>
            <p style={{float:"right",color:"darkGray",paddingRight: "46px", marginTop: "0",fontSize:'12px', marginBottom:"0px"}}>{this.props.children[3]}</p>
            <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{this.props.children[4]}</div>
    </div>  


      );
    }
 });

 export default ShowThisDiv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of how you can hide the buttons and show the relevant Component while specifying only one `handleClick` method: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/BLGmvd

```
const ParentComponentStyle = {
      width:300,
      height:60,
      backgroundColor:"#343458"
};


class ParentCompnent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonPressedA: false,
      buttonPressedB: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(evt) {
    this.setState({
      [`buttonPressed${evt.target.id}`]: !this.state[`buttonPressed${evt.target.id}`]
    });
  }

  render() {
    let renderContent;

    if (this.state.buttonPressedA) {
      renderContent = (
        <DivA>
          <p>Child 0A</p>
          <p>Child 1A</p>
          <p>Child 2A</p>
          <p>Child 3A</p>
          <p>Child 4A</p>
        </DivA>
      );
    } else if (this.state.buttonPressedB) {
      renderContent = (
        <DivB>
          <p>Child 0B</p>
          <p>Child 1B</p>
          <p>Child 2B</p>
          <p>Child 3B</p>
          <p>Child 4B</p>
        </DivB>
      );

    } else {
      renderContent = (
        <div className="DivToHide" style={ParentComponentStyle}> 
          <button onClick={this.handleClick} id="A">
            Replace me with DivA
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick} id="B">
            Replace me with DivB
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return(
      <div>  
        {renderContent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const DivStyleA = {
  width:300,
  height:200,
  backgroundColor:"green"
};

const DivA = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div style={DivStyleA}>
        DivA
        <div style={{float:'left'}}>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
        <p style={{float:"left", color:"white",marginTop: "7px"}}>{this.props.children[1]}</p>
        <div style={{float:"right"}}>{this.props.children[2]}</div>
        <p style={{float:"right",color:"darkGray",paddingRight: "46px", marginTop: "0",fontSize:'12px', marginBottom:"0px"}}>{this.props.children[3]}</p>
        <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{this.props.children[4]}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


const DivStyleB = {
  width:300,
  height:200,
  backgroundColor:"red"
};

const DivB = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div style={DivStyleB}>
        DivB
        <div style={{float:'left'}}>{this.props.children[0]}</div>
        <p style={{float:"left", color:"white",marginTop: "7px"}}>{this.props.children[1]}</p>
        <div style={{float:"right"}}>{this.props.children[2]}</div>
        <p style={{float:"right",color:"darkGray",paddingRight: "46px", marginTop: "0",fontSize:'12px', marginBottom:"0px"}}>{this.props.children[3]}</p>
        <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{this.props.children[4]}</div>
      </div>  
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentCompnent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I don't want to toggle between the two components, So basically the button should be part of the parent component, and once the button is clicked both the button and the parent component should disappear and a new div would replace them

Comment: OK, it makes sense. I've just updated my answer and added a new codepen link.

Comment: What if I had two Buttons in the initial Parent Div, that when clicked would hide the parent div and show a different div. 
let's say BtnA hides the parent div and shows DivA, 
and in case you clicked BtnB, the parent div would be hidden and DivB would be shown instead.
Should I create another handleClick function for BtnB and bind the handleClick to the "this" context

Comment: Would you like me to add anything to the above or does it give you enough info to move your idea forward?

Comment: No it's all good, I was able to make it work but I don't know if it's a best practice. I basically created another handleClick for the second Btn and I did bind to "this" in the constructor

Comment: AziCode, I've just updated the codepen and the above showing you can achieve this using only one `handleClick` method. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Hey @Piotr, I have a question about state. Let's say that I have a button in each of the children ( one Btn in the blue div , and one Btn in the green div ) . When you tap on the blue div button, the div gets hidden and the green div appears... and if you tap on the green div button, the div gets hidden and the blue div appears). Basically how can I toggle between the siblings.
Should I give state the each button or is it better to let the parent  handle the state ?

Comment: The communication between the siblings is best handled by the parent component.